# Problem with compilation QuickSort [Python]

Tags: python, quicksort

i have a little problem with my quick sort's in place implementation:

```
from random import randint
def particionado(lista, menor, mayor):
pivote = lista[mayor]
i = menor - 1

for j in range(menor, mayor):
    if lista[j] <= pivote:
        lista[i],lista[j] = lista[j],lista[i]
        i = i+1

lista[i+1],lista[mayor] = lista[mayor],lista[i+1]
return i+1

def quickSort(arreglo,menor,mayor):
if menor < mayor:
    piv = particionado(arreglo,menor,mayor)
    quickSort(arreglo, menor, piv-1)
    quickSort(arreglo,piv+1,mayor)


A = [randint(1, 100) for i in range(10)]
print(A)
print(quickSort(A,0,len(A)-1))
```

and happen when i try to compile, it gives the random list but it doesn't sort it, instead it throws"None". I don´t know what i can do to solve it.

Comment: your definition of quickSort has no return, you can't print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `quickSort` function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns return nothing (which is called `None` in python). However, the array should be sorted in place.

Try:

```
A = [randint(1, 100) for i in range(10)]
print(A)
quickSort(A, 0, len(A) - 1)
print(A)
```

Comment: this solved the problem very easily, thx you a lot